# Vaadin - Calling Java from Javascript doesnt work anymore with $server

Tags: javascript, java, frontend, client, vaadin

I have a Java class using Vaadin to call Javascript from Java:

```
@StyleSheet("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/shepherd.js@10.0.1/dist/css/shepherd.css")
@JavaScript("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/shepherd.js@10.0.1/dist/js/shepherd.min.js")
@JsModule("./scripts/shepherd.js")
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {
   public MainView() {
       Button button = new Button("Click me");
       button.addClickListener(c ->
       UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJs("window.startTour($0)", this);
   }

   @ClientCallable
   public boolean get() {
      return true;
   }
}
```

In my shepherd.js Javascript File I'am going to call a method in Java (Annotation @ClientCallable):

```
window.startTour = (element) => {
    let useModalOverlay = element.$server.get()
}
```

Instead of a Result on Click i just get a error in the console:

> Cannot read properties of null (reading '$server')

I dont know what i did wrong, but im sure that everything is fine. I just dont see the problem.
If u wonder why im calling Javascript to then call Java from there, thats because im using ShepherdJS to program user Guides in Javascript, therefore i need methods to call in the java part, because ShepherdJS is javascript only -> See also my Questions from yesterday for instance.

Comment: Same problem here in Vaadin 24.1. Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/advanced/browser-access/#executing-javascript-in-the-browser) and in the `executeJs` Javadoc, Component and Element parameters are sent as `null` if they are not attached when the method is invoked.

Move the invocation on the `onAttach` method or in an AttachListener

Edit: sorry, I missed the button click listener. But then I tried your example locally and it works as expected

Comment: Which Vaadin version did you test?

Comment: I don't remember what version I tested in February, but just tested with 24.1.2 and the example in the question works fine for me

Comment: Just want to point out that the sample code is not adding the button to the view. It is missing an `add(button)`, but I suppose this is only a typo, otherwise the button will not be visible in the browser page